# What is the use of bet.user.id, users.user_name, and users.user_status after FROM in this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that I am using to get the sum of values from a database so as to rank each individual user. The table does not return total sum but sum of each `balance_return` for each user who is verified.

```
SELECT SUM( bets.balance_return )
AS total_wins, bets.user_id, user.username, user.status
FROM bets
INNER JOIN user ON bets.user_id = user.id
WHERE user.status =  'verified'
GROUP BY bets.user_id
ORDER BY total_wins DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

My results return a list of 10 users with their individual sum of `balance_return` and they are ranked from the highest to the lowest. The columns returned are `total_wins` `user_id` `username` and `status`. I needed to know how the result is taking every row on `bets` table with a unique `user_id` , adding the total of `balance_return` and finally giving  ranking according to the sum. Going through the query, I do not see how this is being done.

Comment: `SELECT A As B, <then other columns w/o aliases>`

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks but can you please elaborate more. I would appreciate if you have a good source I could read this.

Comment: They are just other columns.

Comment: the `SUM(..) AS total_wins` is one column that you are returning.  the other things are more data that you are getting from the db. When you get the sum of bets - you need to know which user it is for, what their name is and what their status is.... thus those columns are being requested.

Comment: This is the basic syntax of `SELECT` statement.   http://www.geeksengine.com/database/basic-select/column-alias.php